# Flutter Network Image, loading the same image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make an app that you enter an image size as string in an input field then it gives you a random image from https://picsum.photos/, 
the problem is that if I put a string lets say '200', 
the app load an image, when I use '200' another time the app give me the same image until I reload the whole app.
If there is a way to make the app load different image every time I press the button.

here is some code I used:

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
              placeholder: 'lib/img/loading.gif',
              image: 'https://picsum.photos/${globals.imageSize}',
            ),
```

```
Container(
              width: 100,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Size:',
                ),
                onChanged: (String str) {
                  globals.imageSize = str;
                },
              ),
            ),
RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                'Search',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
              ),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('search');
              },
            ),
```

Comment: where is your random image code?

Comment: https://picsum.photos/300
it will give me a random image every time I hit the link, 
that's what I'm trying to use.

Comment: try add setState.

Comment: any update for this ?

Comment: Network Image or FadeInImage.assetNetwork() or Image.asset() some how cache the image for faster loading, and that's good, but it's not good for my app, if every time the user used the same image size the app will send the same url (sending the same url will make the app use that cached image for that url), considering that I rely on the site for random images.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setState` to update the value.

```
onChanged: (String str) {
      setState(() {   
      str = globals.imageSize; 
    });          
  },
```